# Is there a solution in Rabbitmq, a consumer doesn't take other queue until the other consumer complete?

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

I have send message api to my users.
When I send to message from my x numbers I need to wait 10-15 seconds for doesn't get ban from whatsapp.
I'm using 5 different senders and 5 consumers in rabbitmq. When message came from postgres_notify it's adding to queue and I'm checking sender number. If its numberx I'm sending message with post requests. But When I add 10 queue to rabbitmq, It's waiting x consumers complete. If number x,y,z and consumerx need to take x, consumery need to take y and ... How can I do that?

```
async function connect() {
    try {
        const connection = await amqp.connect(opts);
        connection.on("error", (error) => {
            console.error("Connection error : ", error);
        });

        const channel = await connection.createChannel();
        channel.on("error", (error) => {
            console.error("Channel error : ", error);
        });
        const result = await channel.assertQueue(process.env.RABBITMQ_CHANNEL_CP);
        console.log("Waiting for Whatsapp Message");


        channel.prefetch(1);
        channel.consume(process.env.RABBITMQ_CHANNEL_CP, message => {
            let msg = JSON.parse(message.content.toString());
            if (parseInt(msg.sender) == senderx){
                setTimeout(() => {
                    ws.getWhatsappSender(msg.sender, (err, response) => {
                        if (response){
                            try{
                                dosomething()
                                channel.ack(message);
                            }
                            catch (e) {
                                channel.reject(message,true);
                                channel.ack(message);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }, Math.floor(Math.random() * (15 - 10 + 1)) + 10);
            }
            else{
                channel.nack(message, false, true);
            }
            
        }, {noAck: false});
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
        console.log("Create SMS Queue Error", e);
    }
}
```

I'm trying setTimeout function.